# JNA memory clean up

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks, native, jna

As per documentation of [JNA](http://api.suwish.com/jna/index.html?com/sun/jna/StringArray.html) for Memory class, finalize() method needs to be called when memory need to release which has no longer reference. But in [JNA example](https://www.eshayne.com/jnaex/index.html?example=13), it is mentioned that Memory object is getting released when it is out of scope.

```
// note: like Memory, StringArray will free the contiguous block of memory it copied the Strings into when the instance goes out of scope
```

The questions are :

- Does it mean, Memory class object is calling finalize() internally when it is out of scope and frees the underlying native memory?
- The [StringArray](http://api.suwish.com/jna/com/sun/jna/StringArray.html) class and [Memory](http://api.suwish.com/jna/index.html?com/sun/jna/StringArray.html) class are same in behavior w.r.t. memory management? and how?

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**

As of JNA 5.12.1, JNA's `Memory` class no longer uses `finalize()` to free memory.  It registers a Cleaner (custom internal class based on JDK9+ Cleaner implementation) which releases the native memory using a separate thread.

Along with this change, `Memory` was made `Closeable` (JDK6) which extends `AutoCloseable` in JDK7+ implementations.  You may release the native memory simply by calling `close()` or better, allocating the memory in a `try-with-resources` block:

```java
try (Memory m = new Memory(123)) {
  // use m
}
```

**Original answer:**

To elaborate on [Matthias Bläsing's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69441480/1161484) in light of the specific questions asked, I want to add a few points:

- You generally don't directly call `finalize()`. It is called by the JVM as part of the garbage collection process.
- In `Memory` the `finalize()` method simply calls the `dispose()` method. If you really want to get rid of memory immediately this would be the preferred method to call. But `dispose()` is `protected` so you'd need to extend `Memory` to take advantage of this method if you really felt the need to clean up native memory allocations.

  - One such subclass you might consider is one that extends `Closeable`, where the `close()` method implementation calls `dispose()` from the superclass.  Then you could, for example, use a try with resources block and have the native memory (resource) cleaned up at the end of the block.  You'd still have the Java Object hanging around until GC, of course.
  - Note that freeing native memory comes with a processing cost, however, and unless you're really short on memory it doesn't gain much as you still have the Java heap memory associated with the object until it is GC'd.  If you're that short of memory and going to that level of detail to control the timing of the native allocation cleanup, you probably want to go directly to the `malloc()` and `free()` calls yourself and control it at a higher level, perhaps recycling/reusing it...

You also asked about `StringArray`, but the closer parallel to `Memory` is the `NativeString` objects which are members of the array.  And in fact their internal implementation is a `StringMemory` object which extends `Memory` so it would behave identically; that is, `free()` the native memory via `dispose()` via `finalize()` at the point the `NativeString` is garbage collected by the JVM.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, for elaborating Matthias answer and giving explanation of StringArray.

Comment: So @Daniel does that mean, JNA every time takes help of GC to clean up native memory which is out of controlled area of JVM [excluding malloc and free API]?

Comment: @Prashant Yes with one exception.  `Memory` has a `disposeAll()` method which can aggressively free all the allocated memory.  It’s slow, of course.  But works.

Answer (score 1):

The `Memory` implementation of JNA relies on the java garbage collection (GC). Java has no functions to explicitly acquire memory of objects, the memory necessary to hold object data is managed by the VM, allocated when an object is instantiated.

The GC is the process, that frees all memory not referenced anymore. All classes in Java can declare a method `finalize`, which will be called by the GC when the objects of that class are about to be cleared and gives objects the option to do some final cleanup work. In case of JNA this cleanup is releasing the native memory, that is allocated outside the GC controlled area.

It should be noted, that using `finalize` is being deprecated and should not be done anymore, but switch to alternative methods also means introducing slightly different behavior, which is one of the reasons, that JNA still relies on GC for cleanup.